# How to add IF/ELSE function in data validation in-cell dropdown function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create an in-cell data validation drop down menu (in google spreadsheet) by using If/Else function.

Actually, I've 2 range of lists from which I only want to show one decided by a variable cell.

It sounds like this: If A1 is ABC then show range 1 in-cell dropdown & if A1 is XYZ then show range 2 in-cell dropdown.

Here's the code. Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
  function dataval (){

var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B12');

if (cell=="Price") {
 var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C12');
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('D12:D19');
 var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
 cell.setDataValidation(rule);
};

if (cell=="Technical") {
 var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C12');
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('E12:E19');
 var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
 cell.setDataValidation(rule);
};
};
```

P.S.: I'm new to coding & this is my first ever ever post on SOF.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with your code is the comparison `cell=="Price"`. The variable `cell` is an object of class [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), not a string. To get the value it contains, you need `cell.getValue()`, so the comparison would be `cell.getValue() == "Price"`.

You should also handle the event of the content of `B12` changing. A simple way is to put the data validation code in [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) trigger, and check whether the edit was to B12: e.g.,

```
if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B12') {
  // change data validation
}
```

If the goal was simply to have a rule that forces inputs to be in one of two ranges, depending on another cell, that can be done without a script, using a custom formula with `if` and `index`.  But that wouldn't provide a dropdown of values.

Comment: Thanks, Zaq.
Can you throw some light on "getA1Notation"

First, I tried it in the code but messed up everything.